# Re-launch the same function when a child-process is closed

Tags: javascript, function, child-process

I'm working with a js class and I want that when the child_process `this.youtube` is closed, the function `MainFunction()` restarts again;

I know that, if you're inside of other functions, you can invoke this function with `this.MainFunction()`, so I tried the same putting it into the same function but I get the eror `this.MainFunction() is not a function`

Here's my code

```
const childprocess = require('child_process')
class Something {
    constructor(){

    }
    async MainFunction(){
        this.youtube=childprocess.spawn('C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',["https://www.youtube.com/"]);
        this.youtube.on('close',function(){
            this.MainFunction()
        })
    }
}
module.exports = Something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the context which `this` inside `function` refers to. If you want it to refer to the `Something` class, then change the callback to arrow function:

```
this.youtube.on('close',() => {
    this.MainFunction()
})
```

More on how `this` works can be found in [this great post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)